# SVG is rendering differently in Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I am working on `SVG` to render a chart.
[click here to view my SVG chart](http://jsfiddle.net/7MrhC/1/)

When we view this chart in `Google chrome` or `Internet Explorer` we are getting two groups as expected. but when we render this on `Mozilla Firefox`, only the first group is getting rendered. 
I am unable to trace this out. Pleas help me

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is setting no useful width and height on the `<svg>` and also no viewbox.  The result is that it ends up 150px tall by 300px wide (the default replaced elements size in CSS) and clips off everything outside that.  At least that's what happens in browsers that are actually following the SVG spec here, which IE and Chrome are not.